# KendoFileUpload not working with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, kendo-ui, upload

I'm using jquery validation plugin to validate kendo elements in a form. Until now, i successfully be able to validate most input types, but i'm enable to validate the KendoFileUpload. I just want to fire the input when it's required and empty.

You'll find in this fiddle my attempt.

https://jsfiddle.net/syamen2003/yL7rjfa3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#files").kendoUpload(); 
$("form").validate({ignore: []});
});
```

```css
input.error{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <form method="post" action="/kendo-ui/upload/submit">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
      <input name="title" id="title" required data-msg-required="Required field" />
      <br><br>
      <input name="files" id="files" type="file" required data-msg-required="Required field" />
      <br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, the input text work fine, but the kendo file upload does not add any error class to the file input.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your ignore filter is a bit off. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ""
  });

  $("#files").kendoUpload();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yL7rjfa3/31/

Comment: The validation has to be done with JQUERY VALIDATION PLUGIN, not with the native HTML validation.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/validation#employ-jquery-validation